# zipimporter can't find/load sub-modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I'm trying to load a sub-module from a ZIP package but it won't work. How to do it right?

**foo.zip**

```
foo/
    __init__.py
   bar.py
```

**test.py**

```
import os
import zipimport

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
importer = zipimport.zipimporter(os.path.join(dirname, 'foo.zip'))
print importer.is_package('foo')
print importer.load_module('foo')
print importer.load_module('foo.bar')
```

**Output**

```
$ python test.py
True
<module 'foo' from 'foo.zip/foo/__init__.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print importer.load_module('foo.bar')
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'foo.bar'
```

---

**Update** 2015/04/11 06:30 AM PT

The following would work, but is this the real solution to the problem? The `zipimport.zipimporter` documentation explicitly states *"fullname must be the fully qualified (dotted) module name."* and has an `is_package()` method that seems to function properly.

```
import os
import zipimport

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
importer = zipimport.zipimporter(os.path.join(dirname, 'foo.zip'))

def load_module(name):
    parts = name.split('.')
    module = importer.load_module(parts[0])
    full_name = parts[0]
    for part in parts[1:]:
        full_name += '.' + part
        if not hasattr(module, '__path__'):
            raise ImportError('%s' % full_name)
        path = module.__path__[0]
        module = zipimport.zipimporter(path).load_module(part)

    return module

print load_module('foo.bar')
```

Comment: I guess you know this, but if you just want to import from the zip rather than get the module object, Python will do it for you if you add the zip file to `PYTHONPATH` and just use `import foo.bar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will load if you change `importer.load_module('foo.bar')` to `importer.load_module('foo/bar')`.  I am not sure why, because the documentation reads

> load_module(fullname)
>
> Load the module specified by fullname. fullname must be the fully qualified (dotted) module name. It returns the imported module, or raises ZipImportError if it wasn’t found.

Comment: I just came here with the same problem. 5 yrs later. And to load from a program.py inside of mymodule, I had to do find_module("mymodule\\program"). Note, that the front-slash did not work for me. Sure, I am on windows, but that's really odd as python usually allows front slash everywhere. I am running py3.7 and looking at docs for both 3.7 and 3.9 (which don't differ)

Comment: just tried the very same package on linux. You guess it, front slash won't work, you need backslash here.

Comment: Oh no, the other way round, front slash on linux and backslash on windows. Obviously.